# Tkinter: How to make tkinter text widget update?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am quite new to this site and python in general so excuse my messy code. I am trying to make a sort of instant messenger in python with a Tkinter interface. My school has a network on which one can exchange files and edit other peoples files if saved in the right area with the right permissions.

I have most of it figured out, The programm can save to a text file and read it too, however, the text widget which contains the text does not update by itself any and all attempts to make it do so have failed miserably. Any help would be appreciated as i can't seem to figure it out.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry("300x200")
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()


def callback():
    f = open("htfl.txt","a")
    f.write(e.get())
    print (e.get())

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=callback)

b.pack()



file = open("htfl.txt","r") #opens file

#print(file.read(1))
a = file.read()
b = file.read()
print(file.read())

T = Text(master, height=9, width=30)
T.insert(END,a)
T.pack()

def update():
    T.insert(END,a)
    T.after(1000, update)

T.after(1000, update)



mainloop()
```

Comment: Why using a Text? use a Label with StringVar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to re-read the file each time you want to update the widget. For example:

```
def update():
    with open("htfl.txt","r") as f:
        data = f.read()
        T.delete("1.0", "end")  # if you want to remove the old data
        T.insert(END,data)
    T.after(1000, update)
```

Comment: Thank you! this works absolutely perfectly! You have saved me an enormous headache!

Answer (score 1):

T.update() (without any parameters) just after T.insert(...) is OK for me.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `Text`, you should use `Label`. With a function called `StringVar` you can update the label's text. A label is a widget which can display text onto the tk window. To use the `Label` command and `StringVar`, you need to:

```
example = StringVar()
example.set(END, a)

examplelabel = Label(master, textvariable=example)
examplelabel.pack()
```

The command `StringVar()` is just making the text changable e.g.

```
example = StringVar()
example.set("Hello")

def whenclicked():
    example.set("Goodbye")

changebutton = Button(master, text="Change Label", command=whenclicked)
changebutton.pack()

examplelabel = Label(master, textvariable=example)
examplelabel.pack()
```

This would cause the label to change to goodbye when the button is clicked.
Hope I could help :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I have tried to make a button to set the label to the stringvar of the file in question however it just makes the label blank.

Comment: The Label widget is the wrong choice for displaying the contents of a file.

Comment: Instead of using Label, try Text

Comment: Unlike a `Text` widget, a `Label` widget cannot have scrollbars, so probably not the best choice in general. `Text` widgets also support several other additional features.